# weak performance of caret bstTree

Tags: r, machine-learning, boosting

I recently discovered that method = "bstTree" does not peform as well as I expected.
*bstTree* is a method from the caret package that fits boosted trees to data.

Here is what I tried

```
libarary(caret)

set.seed(118)
n <- nrow(iris)
trainindices <- sample(1:n, 0.8*n)
iris.train <- iris[trainindices,]
iris.test <- iris[-trainindices,]

control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)

fit.boost <- train(Species~., data=iris.train, method="bstTree", trControl=control)
class_prediction.boost <- predict(fit.boost, iris.test)
error.boost <- ModelMetrics::ce(iris.test$Species,class_prediction.boost)
error.boost
[1] 0.4333333
```

The algorithm misspecifies 43% of the test data.

So I continued and experimented with the parameters:

```
parameter <- expand.grid(mstop = c(50,100,200,500), maxdepth = 1:2, nu = c(0.1, 0.01, 0.001))

set.seed(118)
fit.boost2 <- train(Species~., data=iris.train, method="bstTree",
                   tuneGrid = parameter)
best <- fit.boost2$bestTune
best
  mstop maxdepth    nu
   50        1 0.001
```

So I found a set of "good" parameters and then tried:

```
fit.boost3 <- train(Species~.,  data = iris.train, method = "bstTree", 
                     tuneGrid = best)
class_prediction.boost3 <- predict(fit.boost3, iris.test)
error.boost3 <- ModelMetrics::ce(iris.test$Species,class_prediction.boost3)
error.boost3
[1] 0.4333333
```

So the error still seems to high.

If I do a similar procedure with the gbm package, the error rate drops to 0%.
I assume that I am missing something.
Can anyone help?

**Edit**: as pointed out in the comments, *gbm* and *bstTree* use different loss functions. Is this the only reason for these results?

Comment: You need to search your parameter space more extensively. The default tune parameters used by `caret` are not a panacea, just some quick choice to see if some algorithm is relevant. Try looking into a more comprehensive `tuneGrid`.

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I already tried to find good parameters. I updated the question. Any additional hints?

Comment: Interesting... Yes, the error seems still high to me too. `xgbTree` seems to work fine too so I just suspect that the `bst` is not as powerful at this point. It is notable that `bstTree` uses `hinge` loss instead of the "standard" binomial loss so that might be an issue. Unfortunately  the `bstTree` method does not allow using different `family` arguments. (+1 for the question BTW)

Comment: This seems to me to be about methods in statistics and not really about R and caret. However, it might help @Cettt get more answers if you can tell people what these functions do.